# Firebase Admin SDK - Get the private key from discovered service account

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I'm minting custom tokens using the node admin SDK within a cloud function. As I'm using firebase cloud functions, the default service account is discovered automatically in the managed environment.

Due to this, I'm able to sign custom tokens using the default service account. However I'm not able to verify these tokens, as the admin SDK only allows us to verify ID tokens and not custom tokens.

Is there any way that I can get access to the private key in the default service account via the admin SDK so that I can use a 3rd part library to verify them

Comment: Since you have to initialize the admin SDK with service account credentials, you need those credentials available before you even start using the APIs exposed by the SDK.

Comment: @DougStevenson, Yes I understand that, however when I initialize my app, the credentials are discovered automatically as I'm using it in a managed environment, so I don't ever need to have the service account credentials exposed in my app. Is there any way I can grab the private key via the SDK?

Comment: So you're saying you can't use the default service account provided by the managed environment?

Comment: I think I've worded my question badly. I have access to the default service account. I want to verify custom tokens that I've already minted using the admin SDK and said service account.

The function verifyIdToken in the node admin SDK will only let me verify ID tokens, not the tokens generated with auth.createCustomToken.

I want to grab the private key of the default service account if possible, so that I can use a 3rd party library to verify the custom token that I minted using the admin SDK and my default service account

Comment: Please edit the post to clarify your question rather than adding a lengthy comment, as that will be much more visible to others going forward.  Please include any relevant code that would help the reader understand what you're doing.

Comment: To my knowledge there's no use case where a developer would have to verify a custom token. That's why the SDK doesn't even provide such an API. Why are you trying to verify custom tokens? They are only useful for initiating a sign-in at the client-side.

Comment: I'm making an application where companies can manage employees. A company sends out registration links to the employees. The employee then uses the link which has a token appended to it that has claims which identify both the employee and the company uid. It means that I can basically link users to their managers. It's a single use token, after the registration is finished, I just use the client ID token for authorisation

Comment: You're better off using some other type of JWTs to implement this -- with your own keypair. Firebase custom tokens should not be used this way. Also custom tokens expire after 1 hour, and therefore are not suitable for the kind of use case you're describing (the registration link will become invalid after an hour).

Comment: Thanks for replying Hiranya. I did exactly that and implemented my own solution yesterday with much success. Thanks!